# Convert to date excel

Tags: excel, date

Could you please tell me how to convert this type of data to a date in excel ?

Data to be converted: Jan 19 2009 12:00AM

Type: 19/01/2009

Thanks

Comment: So you want to type `19/01/2009` and for it to change to `Jan 19 2009 12:00AM`?

Comment: the inverse I want to convert Jan 19 2009 12:00AM to 19/01/2009
Thx

Comment: Is your date always 2 digit long? E.g. `Jan 01 2009 12:00AM` or `Jan 1 2009 12:00AM`

Comment: text to column, fixed with, mdy and skip, finish.

Comment: Date are like that:
Feb 16 2009 12:00AM
Apr 10 2009 12:00AM
May 25 2009 12:00AM
Jul  3 2009 12:00AM
Sep  7 2009 12:00AM
Nov 26 2009 12:00AM
Dec 25 2009 12:00AM
Jan  1 2010 12:00AM

Comment: Excel doesn't like your date since it likes to see a **comma** between the day & year, and a **space* between the time & AM/PM.  So, we can put them back where excel wants them.

If cell `A1` contains:

    `Jan 19 2009 12:00AM`

Then copy this formula to the cell where you want the date:

    `=TEXT(DATEVALUE(REPLACE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&" "&RIGHT(A1,2),FIND(" ",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&" "&RIGHT(A1,2),FIND(" ",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&" "&RIGHT(A1,2))+1),1,", ")),"dd/mm/yyyy")`

And it will display text: `19/01/2009`

Comment: ...or, If you still want the time attached to it (and then choose whether to display the time, with cell formatting) then use lengthy-but-working formula: `=DATEVALUE(REPLACE(LEFT(D6,LEN(D6)-2)&" "&RIGHT(D6,2),FIND(" ",LEFT(D6,LEN(D6)-2)&" "&RIGHT(D6,2),FIND(" ",LEFT(D6,LEN(D6)-2)&" "&RIGHT(D6,2))+1),1,", "))+TIMEVALUE(REPLACE(LEFT(D6,LEN(D6)-2)&" "&RIGHT(D6,2),FIND(" ",LEFT(D6,LEN(D6)-2)&" "&RIGHT(D6,2),FIND(" ",LEFT(D6,LEN(D6)-2)&" "&RIGHT(D6,2))+1),1,", "))` and then right-click the cell, choose `Format Cells`, and on the `Number` tab choose a date, time, or custom format, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what version of Excel you're using. Here's how to do it in 2013.

Typing just *19/01/2009* into an Excel cell automatically formats it as 'Date'.

If you right-click on that cell and select 'Format Cells' a box will appear with 'Date' already highlighted.

Select 'Custom' at the bottom of the left-hand list, then paste the following into the 'Type:' box on the right.
*dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM*

## EDIT

You can also select just 'Date' rather than custom, which will do what you've asked in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

With text in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,3) & MID(A1,1,4) & MID(A1,8,4))
```

and format as you wish.

[image]